# Count the number of foreground and background pixels in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Take an image of the letter 'B' for example:

[image].
If we draw the straight line 4-side of the letter 'B', then it will create a rectangle box. I have to find number of foreground and background pixels within this bounding box(Recangle Box) on the above picture. I did not get the result.pls help me. thank you.

This is my code:

```
 E = imread('1.jpg');
 label = graythresh(E);
 BW = im2bw(E, label);
 imshow(BW)
 L = bwlabel(E);
 z = regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
 nBlackpixel = sum(z(:))
 nWhitepixel = numel(z) - nBlack
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i did not get the result

Comment: run in debug mode and look at `z` and `z.BoundingBox`

Comment: E = imread('1.jpg');
 
 label=graythresh(E);
 
 BW = im2bw(E,label);
 
 L=bwlabel(E);

 z=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');

 x=z.BoundingBox

 nBlackpixel = sum(z(:))

 nWhitepixel = numel(z) - nBlack
 I get error in this code when i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `'BoundingBox'` property

```
z = regionprops( L, 'BoundingBox' );
nFG = zeros(1,numel(z)); % pre-allocate
nBG = zeros(1,numel(z));
for ii=1:numel(z), % in case there are more than one object in the image
    bb = imcrop( E, z(ii).BoundingBox ); % crop the mask according to BoundingBox
    nFG(ii) = nnz(bb); % count number of FG pixels
    nBG(ii) = numel( bb ) - nFG(ii); % nBG = tot number in BB minus num of FG
end
```

Comment: Thank You.How to find Aspect Ratio of the letter 'B' on the above image

Comment: @aryan- this is new question - post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Try using different properties

```
z = regionprops( L, 'Image' );
nFG = zeros(1,numel(z)); % pre-allocate
nBG = zeros(1,numel(z));
for ii=1:numel(z), % in case there are more than one object in the image
    nFG(ii) = nnz(z(ii).Image); % count number of FG pixels
    nBG(ii) = numel( z(ii).Image ) - nFG(ii); % nBG = tot number in BB minus num of FG
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much,But I have to do using regionprops(L,'BoundingBox')