# How to find aspect ratio of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Take, for example, a character 'B','M' or Number '1','2' as an image.
I have to find out the Aspect Ratio of this character or number.
I did not get the correct value, this is my code:

```
E = imread('1.jpg'); 
level = graythresh(E);
BW = im2bw(E,level);   
[m,n]=size(BW);
AR=m/n
```

[image]

Comment: related (not dup) question: [count the number of foreground and background pixels in an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055949/count-the-number-of-foreground-and-background-pixels-in-an-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take the aspect ratio of the bounding box of the character

```
s = regionprops( BW, 'BoundingBox' );
AR = s.BoundingBox(4) / s.BoundingBox(3);
```

See the doc of `regionprops` for the values in `'BoundingBox'`.

Comment: I got error "Use bwlabel(BW) or double(BW) convert binary image to
a label matrix before calling regionprops." After that I use L=bwlabel(BW); s = regionprops( L, 'BoundingBox' ); Then I got error in line AR = s.BoundingBox(4) / s.BoundingBox(3)

Comment: @aryan you get an error probably because you have more than one connected component in `BW`. use the same loop as I used in the answer to your previous question. Or, use `double(BW)` to make sure you treat all `1` pixels as the same object (in your example, this looks like the preferred method).